# What is the theta in this cartesian to polar coordinates problem?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

If x=1 and y=1, what is the theta and why?

I know for a fact that the answer is pi/4 but I do not get why.

Comment: You mean to ask why is the angle $\theta$ such that $(\cos (\theta), \sin (\theta))=(x,y)=(1,1)$ equal to $\pi /4$?

Comment: I know that its equivalent polar coordiantes is (squareroot of 2, pi/4), but I do not get why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given $(x,y)\in \Bbb R^2$, you can find $\rho\in \Bbb R^+$ and $\theta \in [-\pi,\pi]$ such that $(x,y)=\rho (\cos (\theta), \sin (\theta))$, where $\rho=\sqrt {x^2+y^2}$ and, with $\tan$ defined on $ \left[-\pi , -\frac \pi 2\right[\cup \left]-\frac \pi 2, 0\right]$ (so that $\theta \in [-\pi,\pi]$),  $$\theta =\begin{cases} \arctan \left(\dfrac yx\right), &\text{if } x>0\\
\dfrac \pi 2, &\text{if }x=0 \text{ and }y>0\\
\arctan \left(\dfrac yx\right)+\pi &\text{if }x<0\\
-\dfrac \pi 2, &\text{if } x=0\text{ and }y<0\end{cases}$$

In your example you get $\rho=\sqrt {1^2+1^2}$ and $\theta=\arctan \left(\dfrac 11\right)=\arctan \left( 1\right)=\dfrac \pi 4.$

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2#Definition_and_computation

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Nice addition. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

$$x = r\cos \theta = 1\;\text{ and }\;y = r\sin\theta = 1$$  $$\tan\theta = \dfrac {\sin\theta}{\cos \theta} = \dfrac xy = 1$$

$$\theta = \arctan 1 = \dfrac \pi 4 $$

$r$ is simply $\sqrt{1^2 + 1^2 } = \sqrt 2$. Recall, the radius is equivalent to $r$ where $$x^2 + y^2 = r^2$$

So $(x, y) = (1, 1)$ in Cartesian Coordinates is equivalent to $(r, \theta) = (\sqrt 2, \pi 4)$ in polar coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

The angle $\theta$ in polar coordinates is measured from the $+x$ axis, where $\theta=0$ increasing counterclockwise.  Since the vector $(1,1)$ is rotated $\frac \pi 4$ from the $+x$ axis, that is the $\theta$ coordinate of the point.  In general, the $\theta$ coordinate $(x,y)$ is $\arctan \frac yx (+ \pi)$ where the $(+ \pi)$ indicates that there are two angles along the line which differ by $\pi$ and you need to figure out which you want.  If the point were $(-1,1)$, for example, we have $\frac yx=1$, but the angle is $\frac {5\pi }4$

Comment: If the point were (-1,1), can I use 7π/4 instead?

Comment: @Gannicus No, you'd use $\dfrac{3\pi}{4}$, as the point is in the $2$nd quadrant.

Comment: Ah, my bad. But can I use 5π/6? That is also in the 2nd quadrant.

Comment: @Gannicus:  That is the $\pi$ uncertainty I was talking about.

Comment: @Gannicus:  but $\arctan -1 \neq \frac {5\pi }6$

Comment: @RossMillikan Then what does arctan -1 equal to? A google search says that it is -0.785398163 rad. That is not of much help to me.

Comment: That is $-\frac \pi 4$.  Then if you add $\pi$ you get $\frac {3\pi}4$ as we said

Comment: It is, in this case, since we are working with $(-1, 1)$ the angle in question is  $\theta = \arctan (-1)$ means, in this case, since we are working with $(-1, 1)$ that the angle is $\dfrac {3\pi}4$. If we are working with the point $(1, -1)$ then $\theta = \arctan(-1) = -\pi/4$

Comment: It is still unclear to me how it became -π/4 and not -π/6 or -π/3..

Comment: @Gannicus Draw the point $(1,1)$ on the place. Then draw the triangle whose vertices are $(0,0), (1,1)$ and $(1,0)$. The angle you wanna find is the left most one.

Comment: Draw the right triangle with corners (0,0),(1,0),(1,-1).  It is a $1-1\sqrt 2$ triangle.  The acute angles of such are $\frac \pi 4$

Comment: @GitGud Following this logic, won't I always get a-pi-something/4? Because drawing a triangle would always kind of hit the center of the quadrant.

Comment: $$(1, 1): \frac \pi 4,\quad (-1, 1): \frac {3\pi}{ 4}, \quad (-1, -1): \frac{5\pi}{4}, \quad (1, -1): \frac{7\pi}{4} = \frac{-\pi}4$$

Comment: @Gannicus No. Consider the triangle gien by the vertices $(0,0), (1,9)$ and $(1,0)$. Can you convince yourself it won't divide the quadrant in half?

Comment: You always get pi-something/4 if the two coordinates are equal in absolute value.  If the point were $(1,\sqrt 3)$, the angle would be $\frac \pi 3$

Comment: @GitGud Ah, so I suppose that would yield a π/3? That was a helpful graphical way of putting it, but how do I know what points to graph to get that triangle?

Comment: You could look at the unit circle in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_trigonometric_constants

Comment: @Gannicus the angle won't be $\pi /3$, it will be $\arctan (9)$ (which isn't a  known value), (check my answer). The triangle is the one given by $(0,0), (x,y)$ and $(x,0)$. Why $(x,0)$? Because this way you get a right triangle.

Comment: @GitGud So I can always just draw a right triangle and the nearest pi would be the answer?

Comment: @Gannicus You can always draw a right triangle just as long as $x\neq 0\neq y$, but those are simple cases which you can check. The angle will depend on the quadrant.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "the nearest pi would be the answer".

Comment: I suppose that's good enough for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

We can graph this on the Cartesian plane. We see that since $x = 1$ and $y = 1$, we know that this will be in the first quadrant. First we can find the $r$ value which is $\sqrt{1^2+1^2} = \sqrt{2}$. Now to find the angle. Since this in the first quadrant we don't have to add anything so we can just use $\tan$ which says $\tan(\theta) = \frac{ 1}{1}$ which means that $\theta = \tan^{-1}\left( \frac 11 \right)$ which means that $\theta = \frac{\pi}4$. This means that the point $(1, 1)$ on the Cartesian plane is $(\sqrt{2}, \frac{\pi}{4})$.